# Getting the Type of a Subset of an Array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I have a data-structure (it could be an array or an object) that holds some settings data.  It currently looks like this:

```
const settings = [
  {name: 'Albert', value: 'a', isDefault: true}, 
  {name: 'Bradley', value: 'b'}
] as const
```

and the type of

```
type TAllValues = settings[number]['value']  // is 'a' | 'b' <-- that Union Type is what I want
```

What I'm hoping to do is be able to filter this list to get a Subset based on a matching condition in the setting. Something like this

```
type TDefaultValues = FilterSettings<settings, {isDefault: true}> // would be just 'a'
```

where I can pass in a `type` that has this shape, and `condition` and get a Union Type of values for those entries that match the condition.

I would also be able to change the data-structure to be an object if that helped:

```
const settings = {
  a: {name: 'Albert', isDefault: true}, 
  b: {name: 'Bradley'}
}
```

EDIT
Note - There is an issue with WebStorm that treats certain Unions differently.  I haven't found out why this would be, but `Barkers` and `Barkers2` are the same in every other environment I tried.  In Webstorm, using extends on a subset of an object from "as const" is false, everywhere else it's true.

```
const Animals = [
  { animal: 'cat', bark: false },
  { animal: 'dog', bark: true }
] as const

type TAnimals = typeof Animals[number]
type TAnimals2 = { animal: 'cat'; bark: false } | { animal: 'dog'; bark: true }

type Barkers = Extract<TAnimals, { bark: true }>  // <--- never
type Barkers2 = Extract<TAnimals2, { bark: true }>  // <--- correct
```

[image: Initial Type should not be Never]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to examine if setting adheres to condition and select only those that do:

```
const settings = [
  { name: 'Albert', value: 'a', isDefault: true },
  { name: 'Bradley', value: 'b' }
] as const

type Setting = typeof settings[number]

type FilterSettings<Condition, S extends Setting = Setting> = 
  S extends Condition ? S["value"] : never

type TDefaultValues = FilterSettings<{ isDefault: true }> // "a"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmUoEswHMIwLwwNoFgAoGGAbxjAEMBbeALhgHIBBAGwCN4AnKRgGhgA3SqwCu9JpX4xkEACLwAZpVGsoDKF3EwAvnyIlyVWg0YAhLpQAmreAE9pwsRMbtGuogF0YlTKEhQRERQdgAO8DAAyogo6NgwIeEginAxqBi4YKLUnFyeQYSJEQBiyGrc0UjpEAA8AMLgVsgo4AKRMPAAHlDwYFaYlbFo8YPpAHwjHd29-TANfc3I4DAA-FG4AERO4hveDGDwgtwFRTAAKgrKqlAAaiLimDil5Vyj6LXkspcqahpaEToxkA)

Comment: Thanks, this was a big help for handling the array.  But, I'm getting back `never` for TDefaultValues.  It works if I add a type for SettingItem `type SettingItem = { name: string, value: string, isDefault?: boolean }` and intersect with it `type Setting = typeof settings[number] & SettingItem`

Comment: You can see it working in attached playground. I guess the type of `settings` you're testing with is not the same as in the question.

Comment: It turns out it's different in WebStorm.  The playground, typecheck, and VS Code are all the same and work as you described.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Try to check which TS version is used by WebStorm (maybe builtin instead of installed in node_modules)

Comment: I agree it's odd. Both are 4.5.2. What could Webstorm be doing? I added an issue with intellij and there were a couple related ones in there.  It's something with how the 'to const'/readonly union type is created vs the literal one - though I also confirmed they both `extends` one-another.  It may finally be time to switch to VS Code for good.